# Does it sound unnatural to say "タダイマ" after someone says "オカエリ" to you?

Tags: set-phrases

When you return home, the normal exchange is:

(oneself): "タダイマ"
(family member at your residence): "オカエリ"

My interpretation is that "タダイマ" means "*hey, I've just got home.*". And, "オカエリ" means "*welcome home!*".

So, it would just sound weird to say "タダイマ" if someone beats you to the punch and says "オカエリ" to you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it wouldn't sound weird at all. It's perfectly fine and natural to say ただいま after someone says おかえり to you.

Comment: Same goes with 「いってらっしゃい」「いってきます」